# Merging two html that css and jQuery are involved in

Tags: jquery, html, css

With jQuery, I made a carousel with prev/next buttons and a collapsibles/accordion menu.

I am trying to put the accordion into carousel as one slide so I can have multiple accordion menus in one carousel.
I made them and did not specify the pixels because I wanted them to be mobile friendly.

When I try to put the accordion in the carousel, the carousel doesn't display the accordion menu very well. It gets messed up.

Can anybody help and let me know what the problem is?

Thank you

carousel code:

```js
//treat header and content seperatly to manage css and icon

//initial display of the first element
$(".collapsible").first().toggleClass("active").next().show()

$(".collapsible").on("click", function() {
  //in case of clicking again the same element already open
  if ($(this).hasClass("active")) return
  //closing other contents
  $(".active").toggleClass("active").next().slideUp("fast");

  $header = $(this);
  //getting the next sibling element
  $content = $header.next();

  $header.toggleClass("active")
  $content.slideToggle("fast")
});

$("#carousel").children().first().addClass("current").css("left", "0%")
$("#left").hide()

$(".prev, .next").on("click", function() {
  $currentDiv = $(".current");
  //console.log($currentDiv)

  if ($currentDiv.is(":animated")) return; // Don't register clicks if it's animating

  var isNext = $(this).is(".next"),
    w = $currentDiv.width();
  //animate the current div to the left and place it on the right side (out of the screen)
  $currentDiv.animate({
    //left: '-100%'
    left: (isNext ? '-100%' : '100%')
  }, 500, function() {
    //$currentDiv.css('left', (isNext ? '-100%' : '100%'))
    //$currentDiv.appendTo('#container');
  }).removeClass("current");
  //bring the before/next div onto the screen
  $nextDiv = (isNext ? $currentDiv.next() : $currentDiv.prev())

  $nextDiv.css('left', (isNext ? '100%' : '-100%'))
  $nextDiv.animate({
    left: '0%'
  }, 500, function() {})
  $nextDiv.css('left', '100%').addClass("current");

  var isFirst = $("#carousel").children().first().hasClass("current");
  var isLast = $("#carousel").children().last().hasClass("current");
  isFirst ? $("#left").hide() : $("#left").show();
  isLast ? $("#right").hide() : $("#right").show();

});
```

```css
#carousel {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;  
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.slide {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    left: 200%;
    margin-left: 0%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="carousel">

  <div id="box1" class="slide">Div #1</div>
  <div id="box2" class="slide">Div #2</div>
  <div id="box3" class="slide">Div #3</div>
  <div id="box4" class="slide">Div #4</div>
  <div id="box5" class="slide">Div #5</div>


</div>
<div>


  <button id="left" class="prev">&larr;Previous</button>
  <button id="right" class="next" style="right:0 ">Next&rarr;</button>

</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ykbgT/11534/

accordion

```js
 $( function() {
//treat header and content seperatly to manage css and icon

//initial display of the first element
$(".collapsible").first().toggleClass("active").next().show()

$(".collapsible").on("click", function() {
 //in case of clicking again the same element already open
 if($(this).hasClass("active")) return
 //closing other contents
 $(".active").toggleClass("active").next().slideUp("fast");
  
  $header = $(this);
  //getting the next sibling element
  $content = $header.next();
  
 $header.toggleClass("active")
  $content.slideToggle("fast")
});

  } );
```

```css
.collapsible {
  background-color: #666;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: solid 1px #222;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.active {
  background-color: #333;
}

@media (hover: hover) {
  .collapsible:hover {
    background-color: #777;
  }
}

.collapsible:after {
  content: '\002B';
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.active:after {
  content: "\2212";
}

.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  /* max-height: 0; */
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <h3>Please complete your meal selection.</h3>
  <h1>Breakfast</h1>
  <button class="collapsible">Entrees Limit 2</button>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>
  <button class="collapsible">Beverages Limit 2</button>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>
  <button class="collapsible">Sides Limit 3</button>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>
  <button class="collapsible">Hot Cereal Limit 1</button>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>
  <button class="collapsible">Condiments</button>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>

</body>
```

```
http://jsfiddle.net/9oqt1eyz/87
```

Comment: could you post a fiddle of the accordions(only) working ? There is no mention of the collapsible class in your html, if you add it you may have more success...

Answer (score 1):

You are struggling with the position Absolute on the accordian.. You should add another class to all the slide (I have added box class) and set carousal styles to box class.

The class worked for me is below:

```
.slide {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 0%;
}
.box{
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    left: 200%;
}

.accordian > div, .accordian button{
  position: relative;
}
```

Code snippet is as below: Also you can test it here - http://jsfiddle.net/ykbgT/11570/

```js
//treat header and content seperatly to manage css and icon

//initial display of the first element
$(".collapsible").first().toggleClass("active").next().show()

$(".collapsible").on("click", function() {
 //in case of clicking again the same element already open
 if($(this).hasClass("active")) return
 //closing other contents
 $(".active").toggleClass("active").next().slideUp("fast");
  
  $header = $(this);
  //getting the next sibling element
  $content = $header.next();
  
 $header.toggleClass("active")
  $content.slideToggle("fast")
});

  $("#carousel").children().first().addClass("current").css("left", "0%")
  $("#left").hide()
   
  $(".prev, .next").on("click", function() {
    $currentDiv = $(".current");
    //console.log($currentDiv)
    
    if($currentDiv.is(":animated")) return; // Don't register clicks if it's animating

    var isNext = $(this).is(".next"),
        w = $currentDiv.width() ;
    //animate the current div to the left and place it on the right side (out of the screen)
    $currentDiv.animate({
     //left: '-100%'
      left: (isNext ? '-100%' : '100%')
    }, 500, function() {
        //$currentDiv.css('left', (isNext ? '-100%' : '100%'))
        //$currentDiv.appendTo('#container');
    }).removeClass("current");
    //bring the before/next div onto the screen
    $nextDiv = (isNext ? $currentDiv.next() : $currentDiv.prev())

    $nextDiv.css('left', (isNext ? '100%' : '-100%'))
    $nextDiv.animate({
        left: '0%'
    }, 500, function() {
    })
    $nextDiv.css('left', '100%').addClass("current");
    
    var isFirst = $("#carousel").children().first().hasClass("current");
    var isLast = $("#carousel").children().last().hasClass("current");
    isFirst ? $("#left").hide() : $("#left").show();
    isLast ? $("#right").hide() : $("#right").show();
    
  });
```

```css
#carousel {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;  
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.slide {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 0%;
}
.box{
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    left: 200%;
}

.accordian > div, .accordian button{
  position: relative;
}
.collapsible {
  background-color: #666;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: solid 1px #222;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.active {
  background-color: #333;
}
@media (hover: hover) {
  .collapsible:hover {
    background-color: #777;
  }
}
.collapsible:after {
  content: '\002B';
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.active:after {
  content: "\2212";
}

.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  /* max-height: 0; */
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="carousel">
    
    <div id="box0" class="slide accordian">
      <h3>Please complete your meal selection.</h3>
      <h1>Breakfast</h1>
      <button class="collapsible">Entrees Limit 2</button>
      <div class="content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      </div>
      <button class="collapsible">Beverages Limit 2</button>
      <div class="content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      </div>
      <button class="collapsible">Sides Limit 3</button>
      <div class="content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      </div>
      <button class="collapsible">Hot Cereal Limit 1</button>
      <div class="content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      </div>
      <button class="collapsible">Condiments</button>
      <div class="content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="box1" class="slide box">Div #1</div>
    <div id="box2" class="slide box">Div #2</div>
    <div id="box3" class="slide box">Div #3</div>
    <div id="box4" class="slide box">Div #4</div>
    <div id="box5" class="slide box">Div #5</div>
  

</div>
<div>


 <button id="left" class="prev" >&larr;Previous</button>
 <button id="right"  class="next" style="right:0 ">Next&rarr;</button> 

</div>
```

Comment: I have a follow-up question. How can I add another div below the carousel (I am trying to add a div class=footer, that embraces two buttons so whenever user clicks the button. the button wouldn't move and stay there (right below the carousel or the last content) and only the content above it will slide. Here's edited fiddle: jsfiddle.net/ykbgT/11654

Comment: Below the carousel or inside the carousel (not in the slide div)?

Comment: If you want buttons inside carousel just like slide div, you need to use slide class instead of carousel id in javascript.. I have updated your jsfiddle.. You can test it here. http://jsfiddle.net/ykbgT/11689/

Comment: If you find everything okay in the previous question, please accept my answer. Glad to help you. Thanks :)